# angular 4 flexbox vertical alignment and layout in nested containers

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, nested-forms

Trying to mock a practical layout that will be used in a project.  Idea is to allow NESTED containers, some are row and others column.
[image]

The grayish (far right) is the outermost panel containing ONE ROW.
That row contains the left margin column (Green) and the main display column (tan).
The main display (column) contains a row for the header made up of two items different relative sizes for left and right menu items.
Obviously THAT is one problem: the right side wraps.  The other is that align-items isn't centering the left side title.

Sorry for the length, I trimmed down as much as I could:

```
<!-- panel -->
<div
      [ngStyle]="{
      'width': '80vw',
      'height': '100vh',
      'background-color':'beige',
      'border':'1px solid red',
      'display': 'flex',
      'flex-direction': 'row'
      }"
      >
  <!-- left margin column -->
  <div
      [ngStyle]="{
      'flex-direction': 'column',
      'border':'1px solid green',
      'background-color': 'lightgreen',
      'width': '5%'
      }"
      >
    margin
  </div>
  <!-- main panel -->
  <div
      [ngStyle]="{
      'flex-direction': 'column',
      'border':'1px solid brown',
      'background-color': 'wheat',
      'width': '85%'
      }"
  >
    <!-- title bar -->
    <div
      [ngStyle]="{
      'flex-direction': 'row',
      'border':'1px solid blue',
      'background-color': 'white',
      'width': '100%',
      'height': '50px',
      'align-items': 'center'
      }"
      >
      <!-- left title/menu items -->
      <div
        [ngStyle]="{
          'border':'1px solid blue',
          'background-color': 'white',
          'width': '80%',
          'flex-grow': '1',
          'flex-shrink': '5',
          'height': '50px',
          'margin-left': '10px',
          'align-items': 'center'
          }"
       >
        left side title vertically centered??
      </div>
      <!-- right side menu items -->
      <div
        [ngStyle]="{
          'border':'1px solid blue',
          'background-color': 'lightgray',
          'width': '10%',
          'flex-grow': '1',
          'flex-shrink': '1',
          'height': '50px',
          'align-items': 'center'
          }"
         >
        right side vertically centered
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm determined to fully understand FlexBox.  Thanks in advance for your help.
Yogi

Comment: When you use flexbox you should use flex-basis instead of width (direction row) or height (direction column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your title bar is missing `display: flex`, that's why its children wrap. The `align-items` aligns children elements of a flex box. But your menu `div`s are declared to have the same height of `50px`, so they are centered automatically. I created a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/U0MPgmO47ht73DNmeVJY?p=preview) that fixes the problems.

You could also remove flex layout related attributes (`flex-direction`, `align-items`) from elements that are not flex containers (they are not `display: flex`).